# Docker http proxy settings not affecting runtime behavior

Tags: docker, proxy, dockerfile, http-proxy

Setting runtime proxy configuration for docker containers is not working

I am simply trying to coerce http traffic from my Docker containers through a proxy which is itself a local container

It seems like this functionality is part of the Docker documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

What I have done is copied a simple node app which calls an external website. I used the code from here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

This Node.js server listens on port 8080

I then created a vertx container to listen on port 8081 to proxy traffic out to where it needs to go.

In the Dockerfile for the Node.js server, I put an ENV entry to coerce the https traffic

```
FROM xgeoff/node-web-app

ENV HTTPS_PROXY "127.0.0.1:8081"

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But it doesn't work. The proxy server doesn't receive the traffic, the request just goes straight to the external website. I tested this again by changing to the proxy port to 8082, where nothing was listening, but no error was generated. Again, the traffic from the Node container goes straight to the external website.

I tried another methodology, which was to specify the proxy port when I built the image, like this:

```
docker build --build-arg https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8082 -t <image_name> .
```

And it still didn't work.  So I'm kind of baffled.

BTW, I am using docker compose to start the two services. Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    node:
        image: 'node-web-app'
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
    ambassador:
        image: 'vertx-groovy-proxyserver'
```

Comment: "127.0.0.1" refers to the same container where your app is running. Is this the desired behaviour? Otherwise you need to replace that with the name of the container where your proxy is running and make sure they are on the same network.

Comment: I am using Docker Compose to start up the two separate images. I will add the docker-compose file to the question

Comment: Maybe I should use docker-compose to set up the networks and set the proxy to that network?

Comment: Replace 127.0.0.1 with "ambasador"

Comment: I just tried that. The outbound traffic was not proxied to the ambassador. I did this by adding the following to the Dockerfile for the Node web app: `ENV HTTPS_PROXY "ambassador:8081"
ENV HTTP_PROXY "ambassador:8081"`

Comment: I have tried another experiment, super simple with a groovy script that does the following: `def text = new URL("http://google.com/").text` and I deploy this to a docker container with the proxy ENV variables like `HTTP_PROXY "http://0.0.0.0:8000"` and the proxy variable just has zero effect. The code is able to go out to the google website despite that fact that there is no proxy listening on 8000. It should be erroring out and instead it is able to reach google just fine :(

Comment: And another experiment running my docker container with the following format: `docker run \
    --env http_proxy=http://proxy.bigcorp.com:8080 \
    --env https_proxy=http://proxy.bigcorp.com:8080 \
    myimage` and it still doesn't work. I wonder if there is some issue on my laptop or local docker setup that it is just ignoring proxy information? I just don't get this.

Comment: It appears that the issue is with the vertx and node images. One of my colleagues at work did some tests with http_proxy on a generic Linux container and it works fine. No idea why it doesn't work for the Node or Vertx :(